# How to get the opposite side of round()/floor() in C?

Tags: c, floating-point, double

I have `double a=1234.5678`, now I can get `1234` by `floor(a)`, but how do I get `0.5678`?
I know I can just subtract `a-floor(a)`, but is there a function in the runtime library?

Comment: I'm not aware of any existing function, so `a - floor(a)` would be what I'd use. Interested to see if someone knows otherwise.

Comment: Careful: a-floor(a) does not work as indented for negative values ! For example -1.6 returns 0.4.

Comment: @ThorstenS. The question does not say what is “intended” for negative numbers, but it is true that the proposed solutions differ from `a-floor(a)` for negative numbers. Also `modf()` is exact, whereas that `a-floor(a)` returns an approximate result for, say, `-DBL_MIN`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`modf` break a double value in two parts

```
double param, fractpart, intpart;

param = 3.14159265;
fractpart = modf (param , &intpart);
printf ("%f = %f + %f \n", param, intpart, fractpart);
return 0;
```

Output:
3.141593 = 3.000000 + 0.141593

You have to include `math.h`

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/modf/

Answer (score 2):

The function you are looking for is [`modf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/modf).

```
double modf(double x, double *iptr);
```

> The `modf()` function breaks the argument *x* into an integral part and a fractional part, each of which has the same sign as *x*. The integral part is stored in the location pointed to by *iptr*.
>
> The `modf()` function returns the fractional part of *x*.